# HaProxy IP-based ACL not working

Tags: haproxy, access-control-list

I've got an HaProxy front end (version 1.7.5-2) which works fine apart from it's not blocking access to specific IP addresses contained in the X-Forward-for header via an ACL.  Other ACL's within it are working fine though (I've got ACL's based on cookies defined below the IP one).

In my frontend section I have:

```
capture request header X-Forwarded-For len 15
```

and I know that these IP addresses are being recorded because they are appearing in my log file.

The ACL is defined in the frontend like so:

```
acl blockedip hdr_ip(X-Forwarded-For) -f /etc/haproxy/blacklist.ip
http-request deny if blockedip
```

and /etc/haproxy/blacklist.ip contains the IPs that I want to block with one per line.

Restarting haproxy with 'service haproxy restart' shows no errors but when I check the end of my log file I'm still seeing requests from the IP addresses contained within the blacklist file.

I've scoured the web and all of the examples that I can find confirm that mine is set up correctly but it's just not working.  What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that X-Forwarded-For can contain multiple addresses, the first one could be one of your systems.  Now, if you capture only 15 characters of that header ...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.  I'll remove that limit and will restart HaProxy to see what turns up in my logs